# Cant recover form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I want to call the default form from `add_view` for specific template in Django Admin. I will use its values (which I recover from the template by the form) and do my stuff. How can I call it?

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = defaultForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        field1= formulario.cleaned.data['field1'] + "\n" 
        #DO MY STUFF
    else:
        raise raise ValidationError(_("Error1"), code='Error1')

return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin/db/table_name/")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModelAdmin has 'get_form' method:

```
...
        default_form = self.get_form(request)
        form = default_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=None)
...
```

Take look docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form

Comment: Exception appears in --form = self.get_form(request.POST)--. 
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: Sorry @EliasMP, 'get_form' return Form Class, and not Form Object, I've fixed the answer, sorry again.

Comment: Nothing at all. You´re helping me. Now looks like it works but when I try to do:
form.is_valid():
returns 'model_name' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
@Anderson-Lima

Comment: @EliasMP try form.cleaned_data['field1'] instead form.cleaned.data['field1']

Comment: Nope... The same error appears. The debug show me this error in if form.is_valid():

Comment: @EliasMP, I have checked here with two forms, one valid and one invalid, both have cleaned_data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108430/discussion-between-eliasmp-and-anderson-lima).